# Unstacking a stacked dataframe unstacks columns in a different order

Tags: r

Using R 3.1.0

```
a = as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(1:100, function(x) { c(1,2,3)})))
b = unstack(stack(a))
# Returns FALSE
all(colnames(a) == colnames(b))
```

The documentation on stack/unstack says unstacking should "reverse this [stack] operation".  Am I missing something?  Why do I need to re-order the columns of b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last few lines of the `stack` (see `utils:::stack.data.frame`) function create a `data.frame` with two columns, "values" and "ind". The "ind" column is created with the code:

```
ind = factor(rep.int(names(x), lapply(x, length)))
```

But, look at how `factor` works in general (pay attention to the order of the "Levels"):

```
factor(c(1, 2, 3, 10, 4)) 
# [1] 1  2  3  10 4 
# Levels: 1 2 3 4 10

factor(paste0("A", c(1, 2, 3, 10, 4)))
# [1] A1  A2  A3  A10 A4 
# Levels: A1 A10 A2 A3 A4
```

---

If the functionality you describe is important for your analysis, you might do better modifying a version of `stack.data.frame` to capture the order of the `data.frame` names during the factoring process, like this:

```
Stack <- function (x, select, ...) 
{
  if (!missing(select)) {
    nl <- as.list(1L:ncol(x))
    names(nl) <- names(x)
    vars <- eval(substitute(select), nl, parent.frame())
    x <- x[, vars, drop = FALSE]
  }
  keep <- unlist(lapply(x, is.vector))
  if (!sum(keep)) 
    stop("no vector columns were selected")
  if (!all(keep)) 
    warning("non-vector columns will be ignored")
  x <- x[, keep, drop = FALSE]
  data.frame(values = unlist(unname(x)), 
# REMOVE THIS -->  ind = factor(rep.int(names(x), lapply(x, length))), 
# AND ADD THIS:
      ind = factor(rep.int(names(x), lapply(x, length)), unique(names(x))),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

---

Testing, one, two, three...

```
## Not using identical here because 
##   the factor levels are different
all.equal(Stack(a), stack(a))
# [1] TRUE

identical(unstack(Stack(a)), a)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll never get me to defend the R documentation...

`stack(...)` creates a new data frame with two columns, `values` and `ind`. The latter has the column names from the original table, as a factor, *ordered alphabetically*. `unstack(...)` uses that factor to (re-) create columns of the new data frame. So the phrase "Unstacking reverses this operation" should be interpreted loosely...

To get the result you want, you need to reorder the factor `ind`, as follows:

```
a     <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(1:100, function(x) { c(1,2,3)})))
c     <- stack(a)
c$ind <- factor(c$ind, levels=colnames(a))
d     <- unstack(c)
identical(a,d)
# [1] TRUE
```